# Difference of 2 columns

Tags: difference

I have 2 tables  ..I need to compare the 2 table and find the records that won't meet the criteria

Table1

```
 Order   Price
  123     100
  456     200
  789     150
```

Table 2

```
 Order  Item   Price
  123    1     10
  123    2     90
  123    3     10
  456    1     150
  789    1     100
  789    2     100
```

Result should be

```
Order   Item   Price  Diff
  123    1     10    90( 100-10) 100 is from table 1
  123    2     90    0( 90-90)   90 is freq rec diff
  123    3     10     -10
  456    1     150   0(150-150)  150 is from table 1
  789    1     100   50(150-100)  150 is from table 1
  789    2     100   -50(50 -100)  50 is from prev diff
```

Thanks

Comment: I was going to attempt a sarcastic answer, on how to do it with pen and paper. You should probably tell us which language / application you are using.

Answer (score -1):

```
   SELECT
      t2.*,
      t1.price - t2.price
   FROM
      t2
   JOIN
      t1 ON
         t1.order = t2.order
```